# Scroll to specific section, smooth at first but then jumps/shifts down the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm currently trying to get my navigation bar (fixed at the top of the screen) to work better. Currently, if you press on a link within the nav bar, it will go to a certain section with this code:

```
   $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var target = this.hash,
           $target = $(target);

       $('html, body').animate({
           'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 45
       }, 400, 'swing', function () {
           window.location.hash = target;
       });
   });
  });
```

However, it will go to that section but then shift down on the screen and cover content. But if I press the same section again, it will go to the correct spot. I need it to go to the correct spot on the first click.

When I take out the "- 35" part within animate(), it doesn't shift down and goes smoothly, but I need the "- 35" part to offset the nav bar or else it will cover content every time. What is causing this jumping/shifting? Any advice or information that would be helpful? Thanks!

Note: I also have this code, but I'm not sure if it's part of the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var offset = $(".navbar").offset().top;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
             $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
         }
    });
```

**UPDATE:** I fixed my issue by reading more into the details of jQuery's animate. The parameter "complete" (a function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element) that I was using was not necessary, so I removed it from my code.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the scroll event listener to see if your 'move to section' behaves the expected way?

Comment: It jumps to the sections but still chops off content with the navigation bar! Come to think of it, I changed the "45" to larger values too to see if it would affect anything but nothing changes--still chops off at the same spot.

Comment: Is the .navbar position:fixed ?, and if it is, is the top: 0? and if the top is 0? it is not the height of the .navbar what you need to add to the scrollTop?

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It was position: fixed. I figured out my issue and updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to avoid setting the hash after the animation is completed. As you use an offset for the animation (the -45) the animation will run smoothly to the given coordinates, and then it will jump to the hash position when you set the `location.hash` (after the animation is completed). The solution is to remove the hash from the location (the `preventDefault()` does that), and don’t set it again after animation is completed.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 45
    }, 400, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: any particular reason anyone would ever wish to set the hash after the animation is done? I don't see the point in doing so and I am now wondering why I did it myself in the first place.

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder maybe to avoid de default browser behavior on page load? (page will jump to anchor before the animation is triggered.